# Bulk download of wsdl and schemas(SoapUI export definition)

Tags: xsd, wsdl, soapui, wsimport

We are mantaining a java project that consumes a lot of different web services. Service definitions change regularly and new services are added very often. So we need to automate the generation of all the java clients.

We have a batch script that downloads(curl) all the needed wsdls and all the dependent schemas, then generates all the corresponding java clients(wsimport) and finally generates a jar that includes all the clients and all the wsdls and xsds which. We deploy this jar in our artifactory and we use it in our project. We need to include the wsdls and xsds in our jar to avoid jax-ws calls to the wsdls in execution.

The script has become a monster, because we use very different web services. Every wsdl, has it's own different schemas located in different urls, so we have to identify all the files that have to be downloaded and put the xsds in the correct path in the disk.

Our goal would be to have a script that, given a wsdl url list, downloads all the wsdls and dependent xsds in a folder so that we can execute wsimport against them.

SoapUI's "export definition" tool, exports the wsdld and the dependent schemas in a folder, and modifying the "ws:import" paths in the wsdl automaticaly. Is there any way to invoke this tool from command line?

Is there any other tool that would help us improving this process?

thanks in advance

Comment: This http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/running-from-the-command-line.html is what SoapUI can do from command line out of the box. Anything else, you will have to get at the API: http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?overview-summary.html

Comment: @SiKing, I didn't realise that the SoapUI java API was accesible. Thanks for the appointment. Finally, I've made a Java executable jar that downloads a list of wsdls, and recursively downloads all the imported and included wsdl and xsds found in the DOMs. I took the idea from here: https://www.everit.biz/web/guest/blog/-/blogs/downloading-wsdl-files-for-offline-use